# correct way to join an rxjava subscription with in flight observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a method getData() that returns an Observable.

```
public Observable<Data> getData() {
  Observable<Data> observable = mApi.networkCall();
  return observable;
}
```

There are many clients that call this method, and if the observable has not completed yet, I'd like them to just subscribe to the in flight observable. If the observable has completed, I need to restart the call and get a new observable. What's the best way to detect the observable is complete and i should call the network call again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.share()`. The first subscription starts the observable and subsequent subscribers will receive the same emission(s). Once the stream terminates all current subscribers will be invalid and the next subscription will start the observable again.

```
public Observable<Data> getData() {
  return mApi.networkCall().share();
}
```

Note that I'm only expecting `getData()` to be called once and the returned observable reused. If that wasn't the case we'd make sure that `getData()` returned a singleton.

Comment: thank you so much for this response, I was doing strange LoadingCache things, this works lots better.  Cheers!

Comment: Won't this return different instances of Observable<Data> every time getData() is called? If the caller takes the resulting Observable<Data> and multiple subscribers subscribe to that instance then the result of the network call will be shared amongst subscribers, but if multiple consumers all call getData() then they all get separate, sharable instances for every call to getData(). Am I missing something?

Comment: @neonDion yep you are right, the expectation is that the result of getData() is reused. If not then we'd construct a singleton for return by that method.

Comment: @DaveMoten Is this also an appropriate place to use something like a Subject or RxRelay instead? Where calling the function returns a single instance of the Subject or Relay.

Comment: @neonDion yeah you could use an intermediate Subject but once all subscribers to the Subject unsubscribe, the original subscription to the source is not unsubscribed. This is what is nice about `share`.